# How to I get the login button to change to an icon when a user is signed in?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

On my home page, in the header, I have a login button that opens a modal &  successfully allows users to sign in  but once a user is logged in I want the existing login button to change to an glyph-icon & remain a glyph-icon unless the user logs out . How can that be done? 
P.S. I'm using Wordpress, Woocommerce & Twitter Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
    <div class="site-branding">
        <?php
        if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
            <img src="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DEVO2.png">

            <!-- button trigger modal -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup" id="login-btn">LOG IN</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <!-- modal Header -->
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <img src="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DEVO2.png" class="login-logo" width="80" height="auto">
                            <button type="button" class="close"data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <!-- modal body -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block" id="to-login">LOG IN</button>
                                <a href=""><p class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</p></a>
                                <p class="signup">Don't have an account? Sign up quickly <a href="">here</a>.</p>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php else : ?>
            <img src="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DEVO2.png">
        <?php
        endif;

        $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
        if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
        <?php
        endif; ?>

    </div><!-- .site-branding -->
```

Answer (score 0):

use wordpress [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function

in your case you can use this

```
    <div class="site-branding">
    <?php
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DEVO2.png">

        <!-- button trigger modal -->
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
        <!----you icon here---->
        <?php } else { ?>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup" id="login-btn">LOG IN</button>
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <img src="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DEVO2.png" class="login-logo" width="80" height="auto">
                        <button type="button" class="close"data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block" id="to-login">LOG IN</button>
                            <a href=""><p class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</p></a>
                            <p class="signup">Don't have an account? Sign up quickly <a href="">here</a>.</p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>
        <img src="http://localhost:8888/devo-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DEVO2.png">
    <?php
    endif;

    $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
        <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
    <?php
    endif; ?>

</div><!-- .site-branding -->
```

Comment: Thank you but just adding the code alone seriously throw the whole site off and now it doesn't even open. Any debugging suggestions?

Comment: have you inserted the icon in the is_user_logged_in function instead of `<!----you icon here----> ?`

Comment: Yes this is what I added:         
<!-- button trigger modal -->
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        <?php } else { ?>